# Stimulus.js tab navigation: Clicked tab index returns -1

Tags: javascript, tabs, stimulusjs

I have created a tab navigation using Stimulus.js in my Rails application. However, when I click on a tab, the content is not displayed, and the console.log shows that the clicked tab index returns -1. How can I fix this issue?

Here's my Stimulus controller (tabs_controller.js):

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["tab", "content"];

  connect() {
    this.showTab(0);
  }

  changeTab(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.showTab(this.tabTargets.indexOf(event.target));
    console.log("Clicked tab index:", this.tabTargets.indexOf(event.target));
  }

  showTab(index) {
    this.tabTargets.forEach((tab, i) => {
      tab.classList.toggle("tab-active", i === index);
      if (i === index) {
        this.contentTargets[i].removeAttribute("hidden");
      } else {
        this.contentTargets[i].setAttribute("hidden", true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the corresponding HTML view:

```
<div data-controller="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-tab-target="tab" data-action="click->tabs#changeTab" class="tab-active">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-tab-target="tab" data-action="click->tabs#changeTab">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-tab-target="tab" data-action="click->tabs#changeTab">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div data-content-target="content" class="tab-content">
    <p>Tab 1 content...</p>
  </div>
  <div data-content-target="content" class="tab-content" hidden>
    <p>Tab 2 content...</p>
  </div>
  <div data-content-target="content" class="tab-content" hidden>
    <p>Tab 3 content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on any tab, the browser console shows the following output:

```
Clicked tab index: -1
```

I want to have tab menu that displays content as based on the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wast that the data targets were wrong
The naming for them needs to be
`data-controller-name-target=""`
So in my case because the controller is called tabs that would be
`data-tabs-target=""`

That solved the issue

```html
<div data-controller="tabs">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-tabs-target="tab" data-action="click->tabs#changeTab" class="tab-active">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-tabs-target="tab" data-action="click->tabs#changeTab">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-tabs-target="tab" data-action="click->tabs#changeTab">Tab 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div data-tabs-target="content" class="tab-content">
    <p>Tab 1 content...</p>
  </div>
  <div data-tabs-target="content" class="tab-content" hidden>
    <p>Tab 2 content...</p>
  </div>
  <div data-tabs-target="content" class="tab-content" hidden>
    <p>Tab 3 content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```